# Android custom circular ProgressBar clips

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have floating circular timer in my app which uses a `ProgressBar`. However, a few pixels of the edge are clipped into a square as seen in this image: [image: problem] (on some devices it looks worse)

Here are the relevant layouts:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:alpha="0.85"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_background"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_circular"
        android:progress="100"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTextView"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And the `progressDrawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:useLevel="true"
android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
android:shape="ring"
android:thickness="3.8sp" >
    <solid android:color="#ff205C" />
</shape>
```

To no avail, I have tried various combinations of:

- Setting the `FrameLayout` to `54dp`
- Setting `layout_width/height` of the children to `fill_parent` or `50dp` or `54dp`
- Setting `margin` to `2dp`

Would love any tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting some `padding` to `FrameLayout` and set `clipToPadding="false"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the given below progress drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                   
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
  android:shape="ring"
  android:thickness="2dp"
  android:useLevel="true">
<solid android:color="#ff205C" />                                
</shape>
```